# App.config <bindingRedirect/> for assembly with Strong Name and then use Short Name in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, assemblies, app-config

I think Title is not very suggestive in what I meant to ask, so theres is an example.

I have this method that receives a name of System.Windows.Forms Control and then returns the type. (I need to use Version=2.0.0.0 of System.Windows.Forms)

```
return Type.GetType("System.Windows.Forms." + name + ", System.Windows.Forms,Culture=neutral, Version=2.0.0.0, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089")
```

I don't like the appearance of this method, it seems weird by having that string.

So I was wondering if it is possible to specify System.Windows.Forms Assembly in App.config file and use some short name in c#?

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Windows.Forms" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-65535.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

By Short Name I mean something like this:

```
Type.GetType("System.Windows.Forms." + name)
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get a reference to that assembly, like Assembly winForms = [Assembly.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky3942xh.aspx) or maybe [LoadWithPartialName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12xc5368.aspx) if you don't want to include a version in there.  **Note**: if you know that assembly is already loaded, you can get a reference with something like typeof(Form).[Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assembly.aspx)
2. use winForms.[GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb.aspx)("System.Windows.Forms." + name)

Since you're able to ask for the type from a particular assembly, you don't have to give a fully-qualified type name (including assembly container)

Comment: I need Type to create a new Instance, "name" could be Form, Panel, TextBox, etc.
By doing this -> typeof(Form).Assembly I be able to instantiate any Control From System.Windows.Firms?

Thanks

Comment: well, that's different than the question you asked ("then returns the type") but you could either fetch the no-args ctor and create it using [GetConstructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h93ya84h.aspx) or (simpler) just call [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx) on the type